# Проверка IP адреса регуляркой

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, bash, shell

Пользователь вводит агрумент к скрипту IP адрес, подскажите как при помощи регулярок проверить корректность ввода IP адреса?

Comment: IP v4, IP v6, IP v4 & v6 ?

Comment: Какие вообще требования к корректному IP-адресу в целом?

Comment: А зачем?! Неужели не хватает нормальной утилиты, чтобы этим заниматься? `man ipcalc`, `man ipv6calc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo "$IP" | grep -E "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}"
```

если хватит проверки четырёх трёхзначных чисел через точку, без проверки на превышение 255 и валидности и соответствия "белым"-"серым" диапазонам.

Ещё можно сделать `whois "$IP"`, в русской локализации на **невалидный** адрес whois всегда возвращает:

```
Нет whois-сервера для объектов данного вида.
```

это работает и для локальных адресов, и для доменных имён.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63953/discussion-on-answer-by-archergodson--ip--).

Answer (score 6):

довольно корректное выражение для проверки ipv4-адресов:

`$ echo "ipv4-адрес" | grep -Eq '^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]?)$'`

не пропускает:

```
1.2.3.0
0.0.0.256
x.y.z.t
1...1
1.1.1
1.1.1.1.1
1000.1.1.1
1.2.3.04
и т.п.
```

чтобы пропускало и адреса, в последнем октете которых написан ноль (см. дискуссию в комментариях), надо переставить последний `?` чуть левее:

`$ echo "ipv4-адрес" | grep -Eq '^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])$'`

---

пояснения:

- `-E` — опция программы *grep*, включающая режим *extended regexp*. в данном случае используется лишь для того, чтобы не загромождать выражение обратными слэшами
- `-q` — опция программы *grep*, благодаря которой программа ничего не запишет в *stdout*, а лишь вернёт код возврата (совпадение есть — вернёт 0, иначе — вернёт не ноль)
- `^...$` — привязка к началу и концу строки
- `(...)` — группа
- `(...){3}` — группа должна повториться ровно три раза
- `(выражение1|выражение2|...)` — должно совпасть или `выражение1` или `выражение2` или `...`
- `[...]` — любой из перечисленных символов («набор»)
- `[0-5]` — любая из цифр от нуля до пяти
- `x?` — символ `x` может встретиться ноль или один раз («символом» в данном случае может быть и группа `(...)` и набор символов `[...]`
- `\.` — символ «точка» (без обратного слэша точка является квантификатором, совпадающим с любым (одним) символом)

Comment: уверен, что 1.2.3.0 не валидный ip-адрес?

Comment: @ArcherGodson `whois 1.2.3.0` >> "This IP address range is not registered in the ARIN database. For details, refer to the APNIC Whois Database via WHOIS.APNIC.NET or http://wq.apnic.net/apnic-bin/whois.pl"

Comment: # whois 1.2.3.0
    % [whois.apnic.net]
    % Whois data copyright terms http://www.apnic.net/db/dbcopyright.html
    % Information related to '1.2.3.0 - 1.2.3.255'
    % Abuse contact for '1.2.3.0 - 1.2.3.255' is 'abuse@apnic.net'
    
    inetnum:        1.2.3.0 - 1.2.3.255
    netname:        Debogon-prefix
    descr:          APNIC Debogon Project
    descr:          APNIC Pty Ltd
    ...

смени хуиз

Comment: можно зайти с другой стороны, 192.168.100.0 точно не валидный? а 192.168.1.1?

Comment: @ArcherGodson, `1.2.3.0` и `192.168.100.0` — да, думаю, для хоста они невалидны. `192.168.1.1` — спасибо, поправил опечатку.

Comment: уверен, что в сети 192.168.0.0/16 хост 192.168.100.0 хоть капельку не валидный?..

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, учитывая, что ТС не уточнил, что именно за IP он хочет проверить,0.0.0.0 может быть как валидным (например, для слушающего сокета), так и не валидным. Скрипт выше говорит, что он не валидный.

Comment: @KoVadim, да, я специально последний октет обрабатываю отдельно, чтобы исключить в нём «просто 0». добавил и вариант с валидным нулём в последнем октете.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, шикардос, спасибо.

Comment: Чушь, `1.2.3.0` -- это валидный адрес.

Answer (score 2):

Убедиться, что IP-адрес записан правильно, можно вот такой регуляркой ([взято отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17871737/5000805)). Это выражение допускает и IPv4, и IPv6 адреса.

```regex
(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]))|((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])
```

А вот пример сценария для командного интерпретатора.

```bash
ip_regex='(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]))|((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])'
if echo "$param" | egrep -q "$ip_regex"; then
  // теперь в переменной $param что-то похожее на IP-адрес ...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Для IPv4 я использовал:

```
/^(((0)|([1-9]\d?)|(1\d\d)|(2[0-5]{2}))\.?){0,3}((0)|([1-9]\d?)|(1\d\d)|(2[0-5]{2}))?$/
```

Проверяет как правильность IP в процессе ввода, так и завершенный вариант.

Answer (score -2):

```
rexp='(?:(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{,2}|2[0-4]?\d?|25?[0-5]?)\.){3}(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{,2}|2[0-4]?\d?|25?[0-5]?)'
```